# Search an array of threads using class or instance

Tags: python

I am trying to find in an array of threads.
Either by the class or by the instance.
I have tried to generate all possible combinations.
But they are all false.

As long as one works, I don't care if it's class or instance, only that when I search in the harray I'm able to find the thread that refers to the argument I gave it.

Snipped:

```
def exist_instance_thread(instance):
    for thread in gv.self_observer_threads.threads:
        if isinstance(thread, type(instance)):
            return True
        if isinstance(thread, instance.__class__):
            return True
        if thread == type(instance):
            return True
        if type(thread) == type(instance):
            return True
        if thread == instance:
            return True
    return False
```

[image]

Comment: `instance` is a `WebServer`, why would `thread` be the same type?

Comment: @Barmar i know is not same type, i'm asking to chatGPT to trying one solution
I think is be equals to JS two objects with differents propertys can be compare ab1 = ob2 thereis return true 
Only want to find if the thread using or class or instance

Comment: Why are you asking ChatGPT? It doesn't know how to program. All it can do is parrot back some code that came from a discussion that contains similar words to your question.

Comment: something is util :D

Comment: It loloks like you want to find `thread._target == instance.start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instance` is not a `Thread`, it's a `WebServer`. The thread is configured to run the WebServer's `start` method. So you need to match the thread's target attribute.

```
def exist_instance_thread(instance):
    return any(thread._target == instance.start for thread in gv.self_observer_threads.threads)
```

Note that `thread._target` is an undocumented internal attribute, so this could break in a future update to the `threading` module.

Comment: may I ask how it would be instead of an instance with a class? out of curiosity

Comment: It's an instance of a class, but not the same class as the list of threads.

Answer (score 0):

How about these predicate functions? The last one is what you want.

```
import threading

def is_thread_instance(x):
    return isinstance(x, threading.Thread)

def is_thread_class(x):
    return x is threading.Thread or issubclass(x, threading.Thread)

def is_thread_object(x):
    return is_thread_instance(x) or is_thread_class(x)
```

What you want is probably:

```
def is_any_thread(threads):
    return any([is_thread_object(x) for x in threads])

is_any_thread(gv.self_observer_threads.threads)
```

Comment: This won't find the thread associated with the `WebServer` instance.

Comment: thread._target == instance.start this is the solution was work provided @Barmar to search in array ot threads

Comment: well I just did what you asked for - your question is then wrong. You are searching WebServer class'es instances?

Comment: only try find thread by instance or class making a loop

Comment: so `gv.self_observer_threads.threads` contains all possible thread classes - whatever they are?

Comment: that is like as global variable for all "like as observer"

Comment: okay I misunderstood that it was about the threading.Thread class.